# Read server response from SWT Browser

Tags: eclipse, swt

How can I get server response from SWT Browser. I am looking for something simillar to `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `browser.getText()`, see http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html#getText()